# Batch - If / Else / If *** echo

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a "Game" in batch and I am not quite finding the right answer to my question.

What i am trying to achieve is:

If money = > 10
echo You Are Successful
and
remove 10 from %money%

If money = < 10
echo You Aren't Successful

Right now I have:

```
if %money% = GRT THN 10 (
  echo You are successful
  set %money% -= 10
) else (
  echo You are not successful
)
pause nul>
```

If this could be answered it would be much appreciated. I am clearly a novice and could really use the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform methematical operation on variables you have to use `SET /A`.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM  enter start value here
SET /A money=20
IF %money% GEQ 10 (
    SET /A money=%money%-10
    ECHO You are successful
) ELSE ECHO You are not successful!
```

For more information take a look at this: http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Further, consider that you use `%var%` to access the value of `var`. `SET /a var = 123` set the value of `var` to `123`. So SET %var%=321 would mean that you are trying to assign 321 to the **value** of `var`, means 123=321. This is obviously nonsence.
So remember: use `SET variable = value` to **store** a value and `%variable%` to **extract** the value. **Never combine SET and % on the left side of the expression.**

Comment: Thanks, I could not find that info anywhere. You're really helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
If money = > 10 echo You Are Successful and remove 10 from %money%

If money  < 10 echo You Aren't Successful     ( no equal to here )
```

Comment: I found one mistake only ,  you cant take equal to ( = ) in both cases.

It should be  greater than equal to  10 & less than 10

Comment: '>' and `<` are not valid comparisons in batch but redirection operators.